# What is this large steel structure used in excavation?

Tags: civil-engineering

I keep seeing these large rectangular structures on job sites they put in the ground.

[image]

I'm guessing something for strengthening the surface structures?

Comment: I believe this is a trench shield or steel trench box, which protects workers from cave ins while working on utilites

Comment: Ahh!!! That's it! Thanks! If you put it as an answer, i'll mark it as such.

Comment: Yep.  And despite them being required by OSHA (I think), you'll still come across an operation where they are not being used.  Usually shows up on the evening news when a worker is buried due to a wall collapsing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about home improvement.

Comment: Is there another meta site you can move this too? Looking at the views and up votes it appears to be useful information

Comment: Note that some people might call it a caisson, though that term more properly refers to a water-tight box.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is a trench shield. It gets placed in a trench after the trench is dug to prevent workers from being hurt or killed in the event of a trench collapse.

[image]

This picture from GMC trench shield shows a partially collapsed trench with a shield installed that would protect the workers installing the blue brute pipe.

Comment: I remember 2 instances where a person lost his life due to that person going into or working in a trench where one of those supports was on the job but not used. One such accident happened at a job near Philadelphia, Pa. and one happened at a job site north of Pittsburgh, Pa.

Answer (score 13):

It is shoring for trenching work.

If a trench collapses on a worker the weight and force of the material will lead to crush injuries.  Even if you are able to dig someone out from a collapse, crush injuries can lead to crush syndrome ending with kidney failure and death.

Comment: The primary risk in a trench collapse is simple suffocation.